# GeoField, Lat/Long Coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, drupal, mkmapview

I'm using Drupal's Geofield module to convert an address into latitude & longitude coordinates. In my iOS app, I'm trying to grab the coordinates it spits out with the following code, and place an annotation at the location on my mapview:

```
   NSMutableDictionary *userData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSDictionary *pins = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:userData, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"und", nil]];

    NSDictionary *morepins = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pins] forKey:@"field_position"];

            NSLog(@"%@", userData);
            NSLog(@"%@", morepins);


   CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {[[morepins objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[morepins objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue]};


    mapPin *ann = [[mapPin alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"You are here";
    ann.subtitle = @"Let's go!";
    ann.coordinate = coord;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

However when I log userData and morepins, both are empty. I'm using the Drupal iOS SDK - does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to grab the lat and lon fields. Here is how Drupal is displaying the data:

[image]

Comment: I may be mistaken since I’m not experienced with the Drupal iOS SDK, but your code doesn’t show that you are actually making a network request anywhere. If you are retrieving data from a server, then your code would have the appearance of a network request. Instead, it appears you are only setting up the dictionaries that probably need to be submitted to the server to get a response.

Comment: @DanielZhang the Drupal SDK connects to the server for me via an endpoint. It's the three NSDictionary lines I'm not so sure I've written correctly in regards to the XML structure above...

Comment: I see. It would be helpful if you also share the data you are getting back from the endpoint. As it stands, you are creating `userData` as an empty dictionary and that’s why it is being logged as being empty.